# Assistance with the (XLtoright) function. VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I want to paste a column selection (a2:a200) to the next available column to the right.
I am having trouble doing this.
Here I am copying the data from Tables and pasting it in the last available column to the right.

```
Sub CopyMonthData() Worksheets("Tables").Range("d2:d200").Copy _ 
Worksheets("SalesInvoicesMonth").Range("a" & Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(1, 0) End Sub
```

How can I make this work?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `UsedRange` instead.

```
Sub CopyMonthData()
    Dim iLastCol as Integer
    With Worksheets("SalesInvoicesMonth")
        iLastCol = .UsedRange.Column + .UsedRange.Columns.Count - 1
        Worksheets("Tables").Range("d2:d200").Copy .Cells(1,iLastCol + 1)
    End With
End Sub
```

Declaring `iLastCol` helps you understand how to calculate the value but the variable is not required. You could replace it in the copy function by its actual value --> `- 1` and `+ 1` cancel each other, so you get `.Cells(1,.usedRange.Column + .UsedRange.Columns.Count)` as destination range.

Comment: `.Range(.Cells(1,.UsedRange.Columns.Count + 1).Address)` - a.k.a. `.Cells(1,.UsedRange.Columns.Count + 1)`. Which is doing to give wrong answer in case `UsedRange` does not start in column A (which is rare but possible).

Comment: @GSerg You are right. I have modified the code to handle ```UsedRange``` not starting in column A.

Comment: One has to question your selection of calling a variable that holds the last column for `iLastRow`

Comment: @TomBrunberg It is unnecessary indeed. I added it so Andrew (the person asking) could easily understand how the destination column is calculated.

Comment: Wouldn't `iLastCol` be more appropriate ?

Comment: Maybe we have a language problem. You do calculate the last column (which was the question). My comment was aimed at the name `iLastRow`, of the variable, to which you assign the result of your last column calculation. Why call it `iLastRow` instead of `iLastCol`, like @CPD1802 correctly noted. Anyway, no need to answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

### Copy to the Next Available Column

**A Quick Fix (`End`)**

- I'm assuming that you want to copy the column range `D2:D200` in the source worksheet (`Tables`) to the **second** row of the column after (next to) the last non-empty column of the destination worksheet (`SalesInvoicesMonth`) and that both worksheets reside in the workbook containing this code (`ThisWorkbook`). Also, I'm assuming that **all** columns in the destination worksheet have headers in the first row, which will be the row used to calculate the column number.

```vb
Sub CopyMonthDataSimple()
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Worksheets("Tables")
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Worksheets("SalesInvoicesMonth")
    sws.Range("D2:D200").Copy _ 
        dws.Cells(1, dws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(1, 1)
End Sub
```

- The first `1` in `.Offset(1, 1)` means the second row, while the second `1` means the column next to the column of the last (not hidden) header cell.

**A More Flexible Solution (`Find`)**

- The following will copy the column range from the given cell (`sFirst`) to the bottom-most non-empty cell of the column of the source worksheet to the destination worksheet starting with the cell in the given row (`dfrow`) of the column after the last non-empty column.
- Adjust (play with) the values in the constants section.

```vb
Sub CopyMonthData()
    
    ' Constants & Workbook
    
    ' Source
    Const sName As String = "Tables"
    Const sFirst As String = "D2"
    ' Destination
    Const dName As String = "SalesInvoicesMonth"
    Const dfRow As Long = 2
    ' Workbook
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    ' Attempt to create a reference to the Source Column Range ('srg').
    
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Worksheets(sName)
    Dim sfCell As Range: Set sfCell = sws.Range(sFirst)
    Dim sfOffset As Long: sfOffset = sfCell.Row - 1
    Dim slCell As Range
    ' The bottom-most non-empty cell in the Source Column.
    Set slCell = sfCell.Resize(sws.Rows.Count - sfOffset) _
        .Find("*", , xlFormulas, , , xlPrevious)
    If slCell Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "The range from the 'First Source Cell' to the bottom-most " _
            & "cell of the 'Source Column' is empty.", _
            vbCritical, "CopyMonthData"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    ' The following...
    Dim srCount As Long: srCount = slCell.Row - sfOffset
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = sfCell.Resize(srCount)
    ' ... is another way of doing...
    'Dim srg As Range: Set srg = sws.Range(sfCell, slCell)
    
    ' Attempt to create a reference
    ' to the Destination First Cell Range ('dfCell').
    
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Worksheets(dName)
    Dim dlCell As Range
    ' The bottom-most non-empty cell in the last non-empty column.
    Set dlCell = dws.Cells.Find("*", , xlFormulas, , xlByColumns, xlPrevious)
    Dim dCol As Long
    If dlCell Is Nothing Then ' The Destination Worksheet is empty.
        dCol = 1
    Else
        If dlCell.Column = dws.Columns.Count Then
            MsgBox "The 'Destination Last Column' is not empty.", _
                vbCritical, "CopyMonthData"
            Exit Sub
        Else
            dCol = dlCell.Column + 1
        End If
    End If
    Dim dfCell As Range: Set dfCell = dws.Cells(dfRow, dCol)
    
    ' Copy
    
    ' Copy values, formats and formulas.
    srg.Copy dfCell
    
    ' Or copy values (only) by assignment (more efficient (faster)).
    'dfCell.Resize(srCount).Value = srg.Value
    
    dfCell.EntireColumn.AutoFit

End Sub
```